# Prince of Persia - Original code

Tags: emulation

Any way to run original Prince of Persia code?
The code is [hosted here](https://github.com/jmechner/Prince-of-Persia-Apple-II).

Or if it is out of possible what is the best incarnation of this game ? PC/Amiga or whatever porting ?

Comment: if you can compile it for dos, you can run it on dosbox.

Comment: Unfortunately the code linked is not a port for DOS.

Comment: I think how to set up your development environment is off topic here. It's just coincidental that you're setting it up for a game.

Answer (score 5):

According to the readme, it's written in 6502 assembly language. That means it is programmed especially for the MOS Technology 6502 CPU which was used by Apple II computers and their various clones.

When you get an emulator for the Apple II and an assembler which runs in it, you might be able to compile and run it.

Comment: [Here's a list of some emulators you could try.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_computer_system_emulators#Apple_II)